# Atomic Redis Operations with JSON

Tags: python, node.js, database, redis

I want to store a fairly complex JSON object in Redis but I can't see how I can make the transaction atomic, since I will have to get, edit, then set. In the time it's taken to edit, another get could have been called elsewhere which will eventually overwrite my data.

I have looked at Pipelines but it doesn't seem they will be useful, because the commands execute at the same time? Not possible to parse/edit before the set?

I also can't find a way to lock the document/hash during this proccess.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. Use Redis [Transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions):

```
WATCH mykey
GET mykey
// change the JSON
MULTI
SET mykey
EXEC
```

2. Use [Lua Script](https://redis.io/commands/eval):
3. Use the Redis Module [RedisJSON](https://redisjson.io) which supports atomic commands like:

[JSON.ARRINSERT](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonarrinsert) & [JSON.NUMINCRBY](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonnumincrby)

Comment: Thanks for that, I went with RedisJSON and it's working perfectly for my needs.